# How to define many-to-many relations for Business / Person / Ownership

Tags: prisma

I have following models `Business` and `Person`

```
model Business {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  legalName String
}

model Person {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  firstName String
  lastName  String
}
```

Business logic that I need to implement:

- Person can "own" many businesses
- Business can be owned by Persons and (or) Businesses

How do define a join table that will join Business / Person "ownership" for this case?

I'm trying something like this

```
model Business {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  legalName String

  owners          BusinessOwner[]
  ownedBusinesses BusinessOwner[]
}

model Person {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  firstName String
  lastName  String

  businesses BusinessOwner[]
}

// join table to define business owners
model BusinessOwner {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  ownership Decimal

  business   Business? @relation(fields: [businessId], references: [id])
  businessId String?

  ownerBusiness   Business? @relation(fields: [ownerBusinessId], references: [id])
  ownerBusinessId String?

  ownerPerson   Person? @relation(fields: [ownerPersonId], references: [id])
  ownerPersonId String?
}
```

but getting following error

[image]

Will someone please advice on how to model this relation in prisma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this via [self relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations)

```
model Business {
  id        String          @id @default(uuid())
  legalName String
  owners    BusinessOwner[] @relation("owned")
  owns      BusinessOwner[] @relation("owner")
}

model Person {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  firstName String
  lastName  String

  businesses BusinessOwner[]
}

model BusinessOwner {
  id String @id @default(uuid())

  business   Business @relation("owned", fields: [businessId], references: [id])
  businessId String

  ownerBusiness   Business? @relation("owner", fields: [ownerBusinessId], references: [id])
  ownerBusinessId String?

  person   Person? @relation(fields: [personId], references: [id])
  personId String?

  ownership Int
}
```